# Bing speech API : java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: SpeechClient.dll: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: java-native-interface, c++-cli, speech-recognition, bing-api, azure-cognitive-services

I am using "Microsoft.projectoxford" speech recognition API.

I have created a sample Java application which uses speechclient.dll via JNI interface. The sample application is working fine on Windows 10/Windows 8.1 machines where Visual Studio 2013/Visual Studio 2015 is installed. But failing on machines, where there are no Visual Studio 2013/2015 installed.

I checked failed machine and installed following packages:

1. Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 SDK
2. Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86
3. Redistributable Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable(x86)
4. Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable(x86)
5. Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable(x86)

But, still giving the same error. I am clueless, what dependency is missing. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: On the failed machine, what's the error that you are seeing?